# XMPPExchange: An XMPP bridge for chat

Tags: script, chat, python

### Screenshots

[image: Chatting on The Bridge using the bridge with ChatSecure for iOS]

[image: Console output of the script]

---

You can use it to use chat on CLI too, with the help of [profanity](http://profanity.im):

**Note:** You need to run `/online` when you login to enable relaying.

[image: Chatting on The Bridge using the bridge with Profanity, running on GNU Screen in my Ubuntu Server, connected via SSH on my Arch Linux Laptop on second tmux tab]

(Quick how to use: `apt-get install profanity`, `profanity`, `/connect your-jid`, `/online`, `/msg the-bot's-jid`)

### About

Don't you hate having to swap between a ton of chat apps to talk with everyone? Now you can reduce that a bit!

XMPP is a secure and extensible standard with a ton of great clients.

#### License

The script itself is MIT licensed, but the libraries have other licenses themselves.

#### Download / Code

[Download, clone or fork here](https://gitlab.com/aoz/XMPPExchange).

#### Platform

The script should work under Linux and MacOS. I'm not so sure about Windows due to the use of `make` by ChatExchange.

XMPP clients are available for iOS (I recommend [ChatSecure](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chatsecure/id464200063)), Android (I recommend [Conversations](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=eu.siacs.conversations)) and Windows, MacOS and Linux through Pidgin (or as I like to do, Conversations through Genymotiob).

### Contact

If you have anything urgent, you can contact [@Ave](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/128113) on [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), but for non-urgent stuff, use [Gitlab issues](https://gitlab.com/aoz/XMPPExchange/issues).

### Word of warning

If you're using a client that tries to connect with OTR or OMEMO, it'll fail but the script will post the ?OTR commands to chat anyways, so you should probably force your XMPP client to plaintext.

Comment: Will this work as a WhatsApp bridge?

Comment: @MisterGeeky technically yes.